# pygame hold key to move

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to move the player left in the four main directions, but it only moves when pressed not held down, so I have to repeatedly press the button to move across the screen and up and down don't work.

```
import pygame

#Start pygame

pygame.init()

#Window/Screen/Display

display_x = 1280
display_y = 720
display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_x,display_y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platforms')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Colors

black = (0,0,0)
green = (1,166,17)

#Images
character = pygame.image.load('character.gif')
def chrctr(x,y):
display.blit(character,(x,y))
x_c = (display_x  / 2)
y_c = (display_y / 2)
x_change = 0
y_change = 0

floor_1 = pygame.image.load('wood.jpg')
def floor(x,y):
    display.blit(floor_1,(x,y))
x = (display_x * 0)
y = (display_y * 0.9)

not_dead=True
while not_dead:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==pygame.QUIT):
            not_dead=False 

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = - 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = - 5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5

    x_c += x_change
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0

    y_c += y_change

    display.fill(green) 
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [0, 550, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [0, 450, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [0, 350, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [0, 250, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [0, 150, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [0, 50, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [1080, 550, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [1080, 450, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [1080, 350, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [1080, 250, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [1080, 150, 200, 50])
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [1080, 50, 200, 50])

    floor(0,display_y * 0.9)
    floor(236, display_y * 0.9)
    floor(472, display_y * 0.9)
    floor(708, display_y * 0.9)
    floor(944, display_y * 0.9)
    floor(1180, display_y * 0.9)
    chrctr(x_c, y_c)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
print ("Hello")

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Well as it is, the reason that you probably need to repeatedly press is that pygame's  `pygame.KEYDOWN` event is only fired when the button is initially pressed. Instead of putting `x_change` and `y_change` there, set a variable like `is_left_arrow_down = True` when the keydown occurs and False when it is keyup. Then check (after the event for loop) whether `is_left_arrow_down` is True or not.

Comment: Im new to python and pygame and know how i would go about doing that

Comment: im meant don't know how i would go about doing that

Comment: I added an answer, but it uses some tricky stuff that you might have not seen before, such as `classes` and `dictionaries` if you are new to python. Let me know if the code is clear or which lines I need to explain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I made a simple demo where your character (hero) is centered in the screen and you can move him around with the arrow keys. Since there was a lot of refactoring, let me know what stuff I need to clear up in the comments and I will add explanations to this answer.

```
import pygame
import sys

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, speed=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = speed
        self.image = pygame.image.load('hero.png')

    def get_size(self):
        return self.image.get_size()

    def draw(self):
        display.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

pygame.init()
(width, height) = (800, 600)
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platforms')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
hero = Character(speed=5)
hero_width, hero_height = hero.get_size()
hero.x = width/2.0 - hero_width/2.0
hero.y = height/2.0 - hero_height/2.0
black = (0,0,0)
pressed_keys = {"left": False, "right": False, "up": False, "down": False}

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_keys["right"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pressed_keys["up"] = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pressed_keys["down"] = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pressed_keys["right"] = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                pressed_keys["up"] = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                pressed_keys["down"] = False

    if pressed_keys["left"]:# == True is implied here
        hero.x -= hero.speed
    if pressed_keys["right"]:
        hero.x += hero.speed
    if pressed_keys["up"]:
        hero.y -= hero.speed
    if pressed_keys["down"]:
        hero.y += hero.speed

    display.fill(black) 
    hero.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

**EDIT:**
I see that the `pressed_keys` dictionary caused some confusion, so I will explain that. You might want to read something like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) if my explanation is unclear.

Dictionaries in python are basically like physical dictionaries in real life. Say you are looking up a word like "aardvark" (a **key**) and want to know what it means. You would open the dictionary book and find the definition (a **value**) of "aardvark." Dictionaries are simply a bunch of these `key:value` pairs.

When I initially created the `pressed_keys` variable, I defined four `key:value` pairs, one for each of the directions. The keys were `left`, `right`, `up`, and `down` while the corresponding values were all `False`. This should make sense since at the beginning of the game, we are not pressing any buttons and the player is not moving. Lines of code like `pressed_keys["left"] = True` update the value that matches with the key `left` in pressed_keys whenever a keypress occurs according to pygame.

After I get all of the events that happened in pygame (window closing, mouse movement, keyboard presses, etc.) at that particular instant of time, I now can check the status of my `pressed_keys` dictionary. If the value that corresponds to the dictionary key `left` is `True`, then I simply shift the hero's x-position left a little. The same is true for all of the other directions.

Comment: I just need to understand what works, why and how to use it in my own code.

Comment: Well, which specific part are you exactly confused about in the code? Have you tried running this demo? Try using a print statement within the while loop to print out `pressed_keys` to your console

Comment: I'm mainly confused on how to use pressed_keys i tried it before and it didn't work no matter where i put it so i guess thats a start  to help me understand why the method you used to move your hero around worked

Comment: Yeah it can definitely be a lot to take in at first glance. I hope the explanation I wrote clears some things up. You should probably look at some python tutorials first as features like loops, lists, dictionaries, classes, and functions are really important to programming games without ripping your hair out.

Comment: I was looking sentdex's pygame tutorial and for him the pygame.KEYDOWN worked for him that's why i'm so confused

Comment: I assume you are talking about [this](https://youtu.be/xh4SV3kF-zk?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdLkP8MrOXLe_rKuf6r80KO) video? If you listen, you can hear him making multiple keypresses in the background as he moves his racecar left and right. Also, if you are looking for some tutorial information, you might want to check out [this book](http://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf). Have not personally read it myself, but it seems thorough and is something you can work through slowly.

Comment: I copied his code and pasted it and all i had to do was hold it, i'm not calling you a liar you are the first person i've seen answer this question correctly. I'm currently following this book https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ im on example 32 but understand the code up to 39 ( I took a glimpse ahead)  but when i'm done with that book i will defiantly look at that book . If you coulkd explain how this line works particular then i might understand it pressed_keys = {"left": False, "right": False, "up": False, "down": False}

Comment: Yeah I did not really watch the entire video, just jumped around so I might be wrong about that. Your book also seems pretty useful, just keep going and in a few more of those exercises (say by Exercise 45) I am sure this will all make more sense :)

Comment: just curios how long have you been using python? if you could clarify this pressed_keys = {"left": False, "right": False, "up": False, "down": False} for me and how to reference it later then i can work out the rest of it if i run across anything else. (my understanding of it) pressed keys is how you call it later on left, right, up, down are all variables with the value false when one of them is called later with the value of true it  moves it. I guess i'm confused on why you did that third set of if statements that actually moves it  and why its aligned with the for loop hero.x -= hero.speed

Comment: ran out of characters. but why didn't you combine the first and last set of if statements if  so it would be like this event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pressed_keys["left"] = True
    hero.x += hero.speed

Comment: I have been using python for about 3 or 4 years. I would really recommend looking at the **A Dictionary Example** in Exercise 39 of [that book](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html) you talked about earlier. It shows nicely how to create a dictionary similar to `pressed_keys`, how to go about accessing a value given a key using the `[]` square bracket notation, and how to loop through all of the items in a dictionary (which I did not use in my demo code but will be good to know later on).

Comment: As to why not combine the first and last set of if statements like you suggested, it would not work since you would only be executing that `hero.x -= hero.speed` bit **whenever the key was initially pressed**. Pygame only generates event objects when you first press a key and when you first release a key. By including that additional set of if statements outside of the inner for loop, I ensure that I update the hero 's x and y position every frame, regardless of whether or not a button press occurred and an event was generated.

Comment: Thanks is there anything you recommend me to do to understand pygame better and  any tutorials you think are good for someone like me. I understand all the code in your demo. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could help! For pygame specifically, I think the pdf I pointed to in a previous comment is quite good. Become friends with [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) if you have not already, as is true when using any library, not just pygame. If the other tutorials are not enough, [this one](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/) could be useful as well. Start small! Maybe do a simple memory matching game or a scrolling space shooter before doing something as tricky as a platformer. The latter is currently what I am doing, but in 3D, since I am still learning too!